# adding a user id step in actionCreate()

Tags: yii

I'm new to Yii. I have a table where I'd like to add a user ID at the time of creation of an entry. I've identified actionCreate() in the associated Controller, which I guess is the appropriate place to make my ammendment. The only thing is I can't find any documentation on what I should now do. Can I ask for help on what I should no next.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `afterSave()`. You can add a method like this to your User model:

```
protected function afterSave()
{
    if($this->isNewRecord) {
        // Insert ID into other table here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the field to **primary** and **autoincrement** in the database. This value will automatically be added after calling `->save()` on the new object.

You will be able to access this ID field with `$model->primaryKey`